# "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Device, Version=2.0.5.0..." What should I do?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, console, .net-assembly

When I test this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(SwearJarController.GetLocation());
```

I get the error:

SwearJarController refers to a separate project, and here is the relevant code:

```
static string baseUri = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false";

    public static string GetLocation()
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        var myPosition = watcher.Position;
        double latitude = -45.856633;
        double longitude = 170.500646;

        if (!myPosition.Location.IsUnknown)
        {
            latitude = myPosition.Location.Latitude;
            longitude = myPosition.Location.Longitude;
        }

        RetrieveFormatedAddress(latitude, longitude);



        return currentLocation;
    }


    public static void RetrieveFormatedAddress(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        string strlat = Convert.ToString(latitude);
        string strlon = Convert.ToString(longitude);

        string requestUri = string.Format(baseUri, strlat, strlon);


        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        {
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(requestUri));
        }

    }


    public static string currentLocation = "Unknown";

    static void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var xmlElm = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
            var status = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
                          where elm.Name == "status"
                          select elm).FirstOrDefault();
            if (status.Value.ToLower() == "ok")
            {
                var res = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
                           where elm.Name == "formatted_address"
                           select elm).FirstOrDefault();
                currentLocation = res.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                currentLocation = "Unknown";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            currentLocation = "Unknown";
        }
    }
```

Could this be due to the fact that the Controller is a WP7 application, but the tester is a console application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's because of that but [here you have](http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2010/07/26/unit-testing-nunit-a-wp7-project/) how to try from console (the unit testing way).

Basically you need to changed the `ProjectTypeGuids` node to match the WP7 app, saved the file and then reloaded the project.  Changed node to:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>
    {C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Then you can successfully reference the WP7 assemblies.

Comment: Um... So where do I type that in? I'm having trouble, sorry.

Comment: @user1432233 Project file. But follow the instructions here: http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2010/07/26/unit-testing-nunit-a-wp7-project/ they go step by step/